# Does Firefox not support the oncontextmenu event on SVG (JS without frameworks)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, contextmenu

The propose is to call a contextmenu made by me (myCtxMenu) "attached" to a `<text>` SVG element, using Javascript (no frameworks). Something like this:

```
document.oncontextmenu = function() { // disable of default contextmenu
    return false;
}

(...)

var groupSignal = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");

var gsignalID = "gsignal1";
groupSignal.setAttribute("id", gsignalID);

svg.appendChild(groupSignal);

var txtNameSignal = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");

(...)

txtNameSignal.setAttribute('oncontextmenu', 'return myCtxMenu(' + gsignalID + ')');
groupSignal.appendChild(txtNameSignal);
```

The problem is that this code runs perfectly on Chrome but not on Firefox. :(

If I change the attribute to "onclick" or "onmouseover", instead of "oncontextmenu", it works perfectly on both browsers, e.g. it calls myCtxMenu (my custom contextmenu).

Any idea to workaround this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Any messages in the Javascript console?

Comment: I'm using jQuery for this in my project, and works in all browsers. =) So why not simply do this?

Comment: oncontextmenu is not part of SVG 1.1. You [should ask the w3c](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/) to add it to SVG 2. If it was added to the specification, I'm sure we'd implement it.

Comment: No, no messages in javascript console @Barmar

Comment: Yes, I know @RobertLongson ( http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html ) But, if "oncontextmenu is not part of SVG 1.1", why is it doable using Chrome and not doable using Firefox?

Comment: Because Firefox follows that part of the specification more closely than Chrome. I could cite other instances where Chrome follows it better than Firefox of course. The fact remains that you should take this up with w3c, Firefox will not implement it until it is part of the SVG specification.

Comment: Browsers are allowed to implement things that aren't in the official specification. This is often how new features evolve: they're added in one browser, others copy it, and then W3C makes it official. For CSS, the convention is to prefix new, browser-specific styles with something like `-moz`, but this doesn't seem to be common for HTML attributes.